# Remove class from parent - jquery

Tags: jquery, class, parent

How can I remove class from parent?

[jsfiddle linked here](http://jsfiddle.net/tvg94o5u/10/)

```
const accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');
const accTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.guide-titles');

accordions.forEach(accordion => {
  accordion.addEventListener('click', () => {
    accordion.classList.add('active');
  });
});

$(accTitles).click(function() {
  $(accTitles).parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing js vanilla and jQuery logic here.
Even if it's absolutely possible, I would encourage you to chose between jQuery and vanilla.

To resolve your pb, I would do this :

```
const accTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.guide-titles');

 $(accTitles).click(function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active'); // toggleClass here instead of removeClass
 });
```

Note I had to enable jQuery on your fiddle for it to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/vuk7mpja/2/

EDIT: I correct my mistake, this is the way to do it without your first loop to register click listeners.

Comment: oh, i got it, thank you very much, im learning vanilla js, but sometimes i have to use jquery

Comment: I can't see what you've changed in the code (here in SO, not in jsfiddle)